# backbone view not displaying correctly on initial load

Tags: javascript, html, view, backbone.js

I have a home view in which I want to hide some of the divs on the initial loading of the page. However all the divs are visible on initial load. If I tab of this screen and go back, the divs are hidden. The main function is called within

```
$(document).ready(app.init)
```

so I know the dom is ready. Here is the view render function which is nearly working, just wont hide the divs on loading. This is the last function to be called, so nothing else is affecting it.

```
$('#course').slideUp();
$('#scores').slideUp();
$('#next').slideUp();
$("#content_home").trigger("create");
return this;
```

Any ideas

Comment: do you have duplicate id's?

Comment: Sorry Gion, how would I check for this? This is ny render function http://jsbin.com/urebug/1/edit

Comment: I was refering at the dom. If you have duplicate ids in the dom, jQuery will only return the first match (you could use `$('[id=duplicate-id]')` if that's the case).  As a side note, I noticed that you called `window.top.console.log` in your jsbin. If your code runs in an iframe and you try to access (hide) elements on the parent frame, your actions may be limited (due to the same origin policy)... if that's the case, you could try something like `$(window.top.document).find('#id')`

Comment: Where is `#course`? Is it inside your view's `el`?

Comment: I have updated to include html, http://jsbin.com/urebug/2/edit . removed the unnessary code inside the div's http://jsbin.com/urebug/2/edit

Comment: Course is a div within the content home div

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you have a timing issue.  Have you tried:

```
render: function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#course').slideUp();
        $('#scores').slideUp();
        $('#next').slideUp();
        $("#content_home").trigger("create");
    }, 1);
    return this;
}
```

That will make it so your animations don't start until after the render (and whatever called it) finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, no joy though. Even delaying for much longer. Tried emptying the el by doing $(this.el).remove(); Maybe I'll just cahnge my home tab as a workaround.